# Where to put views creation in MVVM and MVC patterns?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mvvm, unsafemutablepointer

Please excuse me if its repeated topic.

I usually write my apps without storyboards, and put views creation into "viewDidLoad", like:

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    var view1: UIView!
    var label1: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadStaticViews()
    }

    func loadStaticViews() {
        view1 = UIView()
        label1 = UILabel()
        view.addSubview(view1)
        view1.addSubview(label1)
        // constraints...
    }
}
```

And now I want to try MVVM pattern in my next app, and just not sure where to put views creation.
Now I think about something like that:

```
class LoginVCViews {
    static func loadViews<T, T1, T2>(superview: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>, view: UnsafeMutablePointer<T1>, label: UnsafeMutablePointer<T2>) {
        guard let superview = superview.pointee as? UIView else { return }
        let v = UIView()
        let l = UILabel()
        superview.addSubview(v)
        v.addSubview(l)

        // constraints...

        view.pointee = v as! T1
        label.pointee = l as! T2
    }
}

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    private var view1: UIView!
    private var label1: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        LoginVCViews.loadViews(superview: &view, view: &view1, label: &label1)
    }
}
```

What do you think ? I'm not familiar with UnsafeMutablePointer very well and don't sure there wont be a some problems.
And how much it's ugly ?

Comment: I think the implementation is right, as any update to the UI  must be done under the View section only as per MVVM. I guess the business logic of which views need to be added can be decided in the View-Model

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should try the fully object oriented path. A view composition looks something like that:

// reusable protocol set

```
protocol OOString: class {
    var value: String { get }
}

protocol Executable: class {
    func execute()
}

protocol Screen: class {
    var ui: UIViewController { get }
}

protocol ViewRepresentation: class {
    var ui: UIView { get }
}
```

// reusable functionality (no uikit dependency)

```
final class ConstString: OOString {

    init(_ value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }

    let value: String

}

final class ExDoNothing: Executable {

    func execute() { /* do nothing */ }

}

final class ExObjCCompatibility: NSObject, Executable {

    init(decorated: Executable) {
        self.decorated = decorated
    }

    func execute() {
        decorated.execute()
    }

    private let decorated: Executable

}
```

// reusable UI (uikit dependency)

```
final class VrLabel: ViewRepresentation {

    init(text: OOString) {
        self.text = text
    }

    var ui: UIView {
        get {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = text.value
            label.textColor = UIColor.blue
            return label
        }
    }

    private let text: OOString

}

final class VrButton: ViewRepresentation {

    init(text: OOString, action: Executable) {
        self.text = text
        self.action = ExObjCCompatibility(decorated: action)
    }

    var ui: UIView {
        get {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.setTitle(text.value, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(action, action: #selector(ExObjCCompatibility.execute), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }
    }

    private let text: OOString
    private let action: ExObjCCompatibility

}

final class VrComposedView: ViewRepresentation {

    init(first: ViewRepresentation, second: ViewRepresentation) {
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
    }

    var ui: UIView {
        get {
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            let firstUI = first.ui
            view.addSubview(firstUI)
            firstUI.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            firstUI.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
            firstUI.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            firstUI.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            firstUI.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
            let secondUI = second.ui
            view.addSubview(secondUI)
            secondUI.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            secondUI.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstUI.topAnchor).isActive = true
            secondUI.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstUI.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            secondUI.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
            secondUI.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
            return view
        }
    }

    private let first: ViewRepresentation
    private let second: ViewRepresentation

}
```

// a viewcontroller

```
final class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

    convenience override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)   {
        self.init()
    }

    convenience required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
    }

    convenience init() {
        fatalError("Not supported!")
    }

    init(content: ViewRepresentation) {
        self.content = content
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        view = content.ui
    }

    private let content: ViewRepresentation

}
```

// and now the business logic of a screen (not reusable)

```
final class ScStartScreen: Screen {

    var ui: UIViewController {
        get {
            return ContentViewController(
                content: VrComposedView(
                    first: VrLabel(
                        text: ConstString("Please tap:")
                    ),
                    second: VrButton(
                        text: ConstString("OK"),
                        action: ExDoNothing()
                    )
                )
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Usage in AppDelegate:

```
window?.rootViewController = ScStartScreen().ui
```

Note:

- it follows the rules of object oriented coding (clean coding, elegant objects, decorator pattern, ...)
- every class is very simple constructed
- classes communicate by protocols with each other
- all dependencies are given by dependency injection as far as possible
- everything (except the business screen at end) is reusable -> in fact: the portfolio of reusable code grows with every day you code
- the business logic of your app is concentrated in implementations of Screen objects
- unittesting is very simple when using fake implementations for the protocols (even mocking is not needed in most cases)
- lesser problems with retain cycles
- avoiding Null, nil and Optionals (they pollute your code)
- ...

In my opinion it's the best way to code, but most people don't do it like that.

Comment: Interesting, where to put TableView Delegate/DataSource ?

Comment: And interact with some view elements if needed via VrComposedView methods ?

Comment: A UITableView has an equivalent class that derive from ViewRepresentation, e.g. SimpleTableViewRepresentation. This class get the datasource and delegate object (both protocol implementations are own objects!) as dependency injection in init and set them in the get implementation when constructing the UITableView. The implementations of delegate and datasource are very simple again and get their dependencies from ScStartScreen implementation again. Note: TableViews typically have much more complex business rules, so don't be shocked when ScStartScreen results in more than 100 lines of code.

Comment: BTW: I'm impressed that I don't get any down votes yet. Most people are not interested in object oriented coding :(

Comment: Interactions between views are typically injected Executable objects that have a dependency to the other view but hide that dependency.

Comment: I work like that a year now and I like it, but I'm still learning ;)

Comment: by the way override func loadView() {} - nice idea, I'm absolutely forgot about that. vote up for that and interesting way of coding :) thank you for your example