# Using a custom UITableViewCell w/ external DataSource and UITableView in a ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uistoryboard

Okay, I want to have a custom UITableViewCell in a UITableView.

I need every component as modular and reusable as possible, so I decided to put them all in different classes:

My setup now looks like this:
I have a swift file for my DataSoure, a file for my CustomTableViewCell and in my storyboard I have a UITableView beside other UIViees and I declared to use the custom cell.

Storyboard looks like this:

TableView (attributes inspector):
[image: storyboard setup and table view attributes inspector]

TableView (identity inspector):
[image: table view identity inspector]

TableView (size inspector):
[image: table view size inspector]

TableViewCell (identity inspector):
[image: table view cell identity inspector]

TableViewCell (attributes inspector):
[image: table view cell attributes inspector]

TableViewCell (size inspector):
[image: table view cell size inspector]

My ViewController class looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class MyShitViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var importantTableView: UITableView!
    var importantItems = [ContentItem]()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Test data
        importantItems.append(ContentItem(contentType: 1, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ContentIcon"), title: "SQL - Basics", subject: "informatics", grade: 11, progress: 35, action: ContentItem.ACTION_MORE))
        importantItems.append(ContentItem(contentType: 1, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ContentIcon"), title: "SQL - Pros", subject: "informatics", grade: 12, progress: 0, action: ContentItem.ACTION_MORE))
        // Data source
        let dataSource = ContentItemDataSource(items: importantItems)
        importantTableView.rowHeight = 75
        importantTableView.dataSource = dataSource
        importantTableView.reloadData()
    }

    //MARK: Table view delegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // For debugging, never get's called, when some one clicks on any cell
        let row = indexPath.row
        print(row)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        print("height")
        return 48
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        print("estimated height")
        return 48
    }
}
```

My CustomTableViewCell class:

```
import UIKit

class ContentItemView: UITableViewCell {

    //MARK: Properties
    var contentItem: ContentItem?

    private var contentImageView: UIImageView?
    private var primaryTextView: UILabel?
    private var secondaryTextView: UILabel?
    private var progressView: UILabel?
    private var actionView: UIButton?
    private var verifiedIcon: UIImageView?

    private var layoutConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    //MARK: Initialisation
    func setContent(item: ContentItem) {
        self.contentItem = item
        setContent()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        print(style)
        setUpView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        print("coder")
        setUpView()
    }

    //MARK: Set Up
    private func setUpView() {
        self.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = Colors.biology
        self.textLabel?.text = "Test"
        // Create views
        contentImageView = UIImageView()
        primaryTextView = UILabel()
        secondaryTextView = UILabel()
        progressView = UILabel()
        actionView = UIButton()
        verifiedIcon = UIImageView()
        // Add Content to views
        primaryTextView?.font = getFont(withSize: 14)
        primaryTextView?.textColor = Colors.toolbarColor
        secondaryTextView?.font = getFont(withSize: 12)
        secondaryTextView?.textColor = Colors.toolbarColor
        progressView?.font = getFont(withSize: 12)
        progressView?.textColor = Colors.toolbarColor
        // Add sub views
        self.contentView.addSubview(contentImageView!)
        self.contentView.addSubview(primaryTextView!)
        self.contentView.addSubview(secondaryTextView!)
        self.contentView.addSubview(progressView!)
        self.contentView.addSubview(actionView!)
        self.contentView.addSubview(verifiedIcon!)
        // Apply Constraints
        makeViewConstraints()
    }

    // MARK: Layout
    private func setContent() {
        contentImageView?.image = contentItem?.image
        primaryTextView?.text = contentItem?.title
        secondaryTextView?.text = (contentItem?.done)! ? "DONE" : (contentItem?.subject)! + " - " + getLocalizedGrade(_for: (contentItem?.grade)!)
        progressView?.text = contentItem?.progress != nil ? "\(String(describing: contentItem?.progress))%" : ""
        if (contentItem?.verified)! { verifiedIcon?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "verified") }
        else { verifiedIcon?.image = nil }
        let actionImage = getActionImage()
        actionView?.setImage(actionImage, for: .normal)
    }

    private func makeViewConstraints() {
        // Clear constraints
        self.contentView.removeConstraints(layoutConstraints)
        layoutConstraints.removeAll()
        // Force elements to exist
        let imageView = self.contentImageView!
        let primaryTextView = self.primaryTextView!
        let secondaryTextView = self.secondaryTextView!
        let progressView = self.progressView!
        let actionView = self.actionView!
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48)
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48)
        layoutConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        layoutConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        primaryTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        layoutConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: primaryTextView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: imageView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 16))
        layoutConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: primaryTextView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
        secondaryTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        layoutConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: secondaryTextView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: imageView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 16))
        layoutConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: secondaryTextView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8))
        progressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        layoutConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: progressView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: imageView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        layoutConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: progressView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: imageView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        actionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        layoutConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: actionView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        layoutConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: actionView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.contentView.addConstraints(layoutConstraints)
    }

    // MARK: Additional Helpers
    private func getActionImage() -> UIImage? {
        if contentItem?.action == ContentItem.ACTION_MORE {
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_more_horiz_white")
        }
        if contentItem?.action == ContentItem.ACTION_ADD {
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_add_circle_outline_white")
        }
        if contentItem?.action == ContentItem.ACTION_REMOVE {
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_remove_circle_outline_white")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And finally my DataSource:

```
import UIKit

class ContentItemDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    var items = [ContentItem]()

    init(items: [ContentItem]) {
        self.items = items
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Config.CONTENT_ITEM_CELL, for: indexPath) as? ContentItemView else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of ContentItemView.")
        }
        cell.setContent(item: item)
        return cell
    }
}
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work, probably the DataSource doesn't work as expected or assigning the dataSource to the TableView...

The CustomTableViewCell should be no problem, as it worked before and I changed the code that my views get added to `self.contentView`.

Actual output:
[image: actual output]

Expected output:
[image: expected output]

Comment: You seem to be interested in coding reusable components. Maybe this link is of interest for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43426337/6595536

Comment: That's a really interesting way to code an app :D
I'll keep it in mind for my next projects :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasource is defined as weak:

```
weak open var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource?
```

Your code:

```
let dataSource = ContentItemDataSource(items: importantItems)
importantTableView.dataSource = dataSource
```

You do not hold a reference, therefore it will be nil again after end of method.

Solution: Define a class var and hold it as long as needed.

```
var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource!
```

and:

```
let dataSource = ContentItemDataSource(items: importantItems)
importantTableView.dataSource = dataSource
self.dataSource = dataSource
```

Comment: And by the way: you do not set the `importantTableView.delegate = self`.

Comment: Oh good point :D I had it in there some time :) But I used an outlet instead because I tried so many things to get it working and thought this may solve the problem, as I saw it in other projects. Guess what: It didn't 

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't even think about that fact. You made me jump throw my room because it finally worked out for me :D